# Combining Postgres jsonb query statements

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-9.5

I have **test table** with **votes column** and I want to upsert nested jsonb object into it. My current query:

```
INSERT INTO test (post_id, username, votes) 
VALUES (12345, 'testuser', '{"commentid" : {"vote": true }}'::jsonb) 
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_pkey DO UPDATE
  SET votes = test.votes ||
('{"commentid" : {"vote": true} }'::jsonb || test.votes->'commentid') 
  WHERE NOT test.votes @> EXCLUDED.votes
  RETURNING *;
```

*test_pkey constraint is PRIMARY KEY (post_id, username)*

How can I construct this statement

```
('{"commentid" : {"vote": true} }'::jsonb || test.votes->'commentid')
```

So postgresql would read it as

```
'{"commentid" : {"vote": true, test.votes->'commentid'} }'::jsonb
```

is it possible to somehow combine it like in json?

What this is supposed to do is make "commentid" key-value pair if one doesnt exist and combine them if it does.

I have tried using different variations of jsonb_set like

```
jsonb_set(test.votes,'{"commentid", vote}','true', true);
```

or

```
jsonb_set(test.votes,'{"commentid"}', test.votes->'commentid' || '{"vote":true}', true)
```

But the first one erases the whole votes object if "commentid" doesn't exist and second one replaces the whole votes object with second part of the statement.

If it's possible to make it work this way, I'd be able to return this data straight to frontend without any modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing using inspiration from [MatheusOl answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148132/104552).

```
INSERT INTO test (post_id, username, votes) 
VALUES (12345, 'testuser', '{"commentid" : {"vote": true }}'::jsonb) 
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_pkey DO UPDATE

  SET votes = test.votes || coalesce(test.votes->'commentid', '{"commentid" : {"vote: true"}}'))
   || jsonb_set(test.votes, '{commentid,vote}', 'true'::jsonb) 

WHERE NOT test.votes @> EXCLUDED.votes
RETURNING *;
```

When using his answer, "commentid" would still be overwritten, but I don't really understand why.

This doesn't do things very efficiently, as it recreates the "commentid" key every time as a new object, but in my case it will have significantly more reads than writes, so it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered, you want to do:

```
SET votes = jsonb_set(
      test.votes,
      '{commentid}',
      coalesce(test.votes->'commentid', '{}') || EXCLUDED.votes->'commentid'
    )
```

The trick here is to use `jsonb_set` using `{commentid}` as the path you want to construct (second argument) and the third argument as already built value of `commentid` you want.

In order to build the third argument I first took the value of `commentid` from the existent row (`test.votes->'commentid'`) and used `COALESCE` to set it to an empty json object (`{}`) if the current row does not have `commentid`. In other words, it will just assume empty json instead of `NULL` (SQL NULL, not json NULL). Then I simple concatenated it with the given `commentid` value (I assume that it does always have one, otherwise you'd need `COALESCE` there too).

Comment: Thanks a ton for setting me on the right track! For some reason your statement would still overwrite 'commentid' object completely with a new one. And I can't really figure out why, because it seems like it should merge the old commentid with new one and then set it inside votes objects.

This is how I modified it, ant it works like a charm  `SET votes = (test.votes || coalesce(test.votes->'commentid', '{"commentid" : {}}')) || jsonb_set(test.votes, '{commentid,vote}', 'true'::jsonb)`

Comment: Oh. You are right @PijusV. If you could only give a table definition and data to play with, it would be great.

Comment: hey, i put it as text here https://jsfiddle.net/dd0vfeew/1/  it should work. Although I don't think that it will be possible to use it with parameterized querys